# Angular 5 and Mocha unit test - spy a component method - Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '/'

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have a simple navigation component in my app which it takes an array of "navItems" (each item is an object with properties such as route, label - `[{route: '/', label: 'navigation.home'}]`)

this is the Component HTML

```
<nav>
  <mat-nav-list>
    <div *ngFor="let navItem of navList">     
      <a mat-button
         [routerLink]="[navItem.url]"
         (click)="doSomething()"
         routerLinkActive="active">
        {{navItem.label | translate}}
      </a>       
    </div>
  </mat-nav-list>
</nav>
```

Within my component I have the following

```
export class NavigationComponent {

  public navList: navItems[] = [{url: '/my-url', label: 'home.page'}, {}, {}]; // naturally I have simplified this

  public doSomething() {
    console.log('doSomething');
  }
}
```

Now I want to make sure that when a link or "a" tag is clicked my `doSomething` method is called. So in my spec file I have the following (please note for some reason this project is using Mocha and not Jasmin) - once again I have tried to reduce the code here for clarity

```
beforeEach(() => {
// Allows overriding default providers, directives, pipes
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MaterialModule,
        TranslateTestingModule.forRoot(),
        AuthTestingModule.forRoot(),
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
      ],
      declarations: [
        NavigationComponent
      ],
      schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
      ]
    });
});

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavigationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    element = fixture.nativeElement;
  });

describe('...', () => {

 it('should call the doSomething() method ', () => {

    const spyDoSomething = sinon.stub(component, 'doSomething' as any);
    fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('a').click();

    expect(spyDoSomething.calledOnce).to.be.eq(true);
  });   
});
```

I thought this would work but I get the following error:

> 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'scbas'', '; Zone:', 'angular', '; Task:', 'Promise.then', '; Value:',
>   Error{}, 'Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '/my-url'

Do I need to prevent the actual click triggering the Angular router?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you do not actually need to provide the `RouterTestingModule` you could actually get away with a provider. Here is a [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-rk5t5m)

The main difference is I replaced the `RouterTestingModule` with 

`{
    provide: Router,
    useValue: { navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate') }
}`